# Is there a way to find out if a network outage occurred from logs?

Tags: rhel, logs

I have a red hat server running an oracle database.
I can see in oracles rdbms' alert logs that a network outage of some sort occurred.

```
ORA-16198: Timeout incurred on internal channel during remote archival
LGWR: Network asynch I/O wait error 16198 log 3 service
```

I want to know if the server registered something similar.
I'm looking for NIC failures or simply a disconnection from the switch.

Note that the outage was temporary. I can access the server through ssh and I can ping the database service and the server itself, so my only way to tell that something happened is from logs.

Where can I look for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your `/var/log/messages` log file. You could find something like:

```
Jan  6 00:00:21 tseenfoo kernel: [104970.689167] atl1c 0000:05:00.0: atl1c: eth0 NIC Link is Down
Jan  6 00:00:31 tseenfoo kernel: [104980.550289] atl1c 0000:05:00.0: atl1c: eth0 NIC Link is Up<1000 Mbps Full Duplex>
```

Note that those are *network card kernel module* messages so they are *driver* dependant. They may not exist at all or may change according to the different module active on you server.

If you can, run a `tail -F /var/log/messages` and quickly unplug/re-plug the cable (to see if those events are logged).

Check the driver documentation, often drivers offer some kind of *debug* mode you can use to log future outages.